# VBA type mismatch Adding dates via function to find dates in between 2 dates into dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, date, dictionary

I am trying to add a key and then dates from an array dates () data type into a dictionary, but I get a type mismatch error, any ideas?

```
Sub Test_Dates()
'
Dim TESTWB As Workbook
Dim TESTWS As Worksheet

Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")

Dim DatesDict As Scripting.Dictionary

For i = 1 To TESTWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
      DatesDict.Add TESTWS.Cells(i, 1), getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3))
      
Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the function to get dates between 2 dates (i,2) and (i,3)

```
Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant

    Dim varDates()      As Date
    Dim lngDateCounter  As Long

    ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))

    For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
        varDates(lngDateCounter) = CDate(StartDate)
        StartDate = CDate(CDbl(StartDate) + 1)
    Next lngDateCounter

    getDates = varDates

ClearMemory:
    If IsArray(varDates) Then Erase varDates
    lngDateCounter = Empty

End Function
```

Comment: Error is on which line?

Comment: Likely one of your dates is not a valid date.  Also, you may not be aware but when you call `DatesDict.Add TESTWS.Cells(i, 1),...` you're adding *the actual cell/range object* to the dictionary as the key, not the cell value, so use `DatesDict.Add TESTWS.Cells(i, 1).Value,...` instead. 
 This is one example of why always being explicit and using `.Value` is a useful habit to get into.

Comment: ...also no need to clear local variables at the end of a method in VBA: I have never seen a case where this was required.

Comment: By the way, your function should probably return `Date()`, not `Variant`, right?

Comment: @Tim Williams error is on DatesDict.Add TESTWS.Cells(i, 1), getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3)) type mismatch

Comment: @BigBen it works ok with variant but yes prb better to change to Date()

Comment: One of those two cells can't be converted to `Date` - either correct the data, or run some checks in your code and take the appropriate action (stop with error message/ignore that row, etc)

Comment: I did check that, all of them are dates, also tested getDates that works too, might be prob with get dates () array ? I did add it to a collection previously that worked fine

Comment: Try incorporating `IsDate` maybe into your checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like maybe one or more of your rows do not have valid dates in ColB or ColC.

It would help with debugging to avoid the implicit `Date` conversion:

Eg:

```vb
Sub Test_Dates()
    '
    Dim TESTWB As Workbook
    Dim TESTWS As Worksheet, i As Long, k
    Dim DatesDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date
    
    Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")
    Set DatesDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    For i = 1 To TESTWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With TESTWS.Rows(i)
            dtStart = CDate(.Columns("B").Value) '<< explicit Date conversion
            dtEnd = CDate(.Columns("C").Value)
            If dtEnd >= dtStart Then
                DatesDict.Add .Columns("A").Value, getDates(dtStart, dtEnd)
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
    'checking...
    For Each k In DatesDict
        Debug.Print TypeName(k), k, DatesDict(k)(0)
    Next k

End Sub

Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant
    Dim varDates()      As Date
    Dim lngDateCounter  As Long
    ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))
    For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
        varDates(lngDateCounter) = CDate(StartDate)
        StartDate = CDate(CDbl(StartDate) + 1)
    Next lngDateCounter
    getDates = varDates
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks that is good practice and I should check the data. Have found the error I think, I was not declaring correctly, should be Dim DatesDict As *New* Scripting.Dictionary

Comment: The error you reported was "type mismatch error",  not "Object variable or with block varaible not set" so I assumed you'd somehow left out the `New` when posting your code.  When posting please be sure to accurately describe the problem...

Comment: Yes my bad, in fact "type mismatch" was also an error, because i was looping i = 1 instead of i = 2 so first line with titles for the columns. Thanks for your help you put me on the right track for that one, and generally always good practice to check the data.